# Finding MGF from PDF

Tags: probability

Given the PDF

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2\,e^{-2x},\quad & 0\le x \\ 0, &x<0\end{cases}, $$

find the MGF.

I know $M(t)$ equals the integral from $0$ to infinity of $f(x) * e^{tx}.$ However, when I integrate and evaluate I am getting infinity. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Apparantly. E.g. for $t=1$ you should just get $1$ because $\int f(x)e^{0t}dx=\int f(x)dx=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, for any $t\in(-\infty,2)$, and $X$ a random variable with the stated pdf $f$,
$$
M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{tx}f(x)dx
= 2\int_{0}^\infty e^{tx}e^{-2x}dx
= 2\int_{0}^\infty e^{(t-2)x}dx
= \frac{2}{2-t}
$$
The MGF is not defined for $t\geq2$. *(Which is completely alright -- the MGF is not guaranteed to exist for all reals, unlike the characteristic function.)*

As a sanity check, indeed we do have $M_X(0) = 1$, as it should. (For *every* real-valued r.v. $X$, $M_X(0)$ exists and is equal to $1$.)

Comment: when you integrate, why isn't it 2/(t-2)?

Comment: @Liza it cannot, because it has to be positive (you integrate a positive function). Compute the integral, you'll get something like 2(0-1/(t-2)).